# R: credentials dialogue prompted when connecting to access DB that is not otherwise protected

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

We have access databases (.accdb) for metadata from really old processes that are trying to die. I am trying to connect to these databases with R RODBC. When I navigate to the file path, I can open the database in Access without entering any credentials. When I try to load it in R, I am prompted a user authentication dialogue Box (R in Windows), and I can't seem to authenticate. There is a DSN file in the same directory, but when I try to connect to it, I get the following error:

```
 ch <- odbcConnect("this.dsn")
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=this.dsn") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=this.dsn") : ODBC connection failed
```

and ch returns -1

Comment: *When I try to load it in R* ... is this attempt your posted code or different line(s)? Likely the DSN contains credentials. Try direct driver connection.